# Periodically monitor if record is not updated using Node, Event and setTimeOut

Tags: javascript, node.js, event-handling, timer

Here is my scenario:

- Every user checks in every five minutes.
- If some user doesn't check in after 5 minutes, I should be able to keep track of it.
- If some user doesn't check in N number of times, an alert should be generated , like send email or SMS.

Here is what I have implemented so far:

```
var Report = function(attendence) {
  this.attendence = attendence;
  EventEmitter.call(this);
};

util.inherits(Report, EventEmitter);

Report.prototype.addAPSStatsData = function() {

  var attendenceDB = new Report(this.attendence);

  //Promise 
  var prSave = attendenceDB.save();
  var self = this;
  prSave.then(function(data) {

    //emitting event that data has been saved 
    self.emit('attendenceRecieved', data.userName);

    var saveTime = Date.now();
    self.moniterAPSStatsData(data.userName, saveTime);

  }).catch(function(err) {
    self.emit('error', err);
  });
};

Report.prototype.moniterAPSStatsData = function(userName, time) {

  var cacheKey = appConfig.CACHE_KEY_UserTimeInterval + userName;
  var prevTimer = memoryCache.get(cacheKey);

  if(!prevTimer) 
    clearTimeout(prevTimer);

  var timer = setTimeout(this.moniterCallBackAfterInterval, (5 * 60000), userName, time ,cacheKey);

  //Putting timout in cache so later on it can be clearedout if the new attendence comes in 
  memoryCache.set(cacheKey, timer);

};

Report.prototype.moniterCallBackAfterInterval = function(userName, time ,cacheKey) {
  //Removing from cache
  memoryCache.del(cacheKey);

  //Emitting event so email can be send out
  this.emit('ReportNotRecieved_SENDEMAIL');
};
```

- Do you think this is a good approach?
- Will it hold in a production environment?
- Are there any alternatives to `setTimeOut` which can be used here?

Comment: I would actually recommend doing this in redis instead of in a node program.

Comment: Sorry if my question seems annoying but can you please elaborate on this. I am totally new to realms of JS and from what I gathered about REDIS , its in memory storage thingi.

Comment: What do you mean from "every one checks"? Every server running this code? What are they "missing"? It looks to me like you're trying to invalidate a key after a set interval. As Dan mentioned you're probably better off having Redis handle this. See the [expire command](http://redis.io/commands/expire).

Comment: I have updated my question. The main purpose is to send out an email if some one doesn't report in given time. Using cahce to keep track of setTimeout.